# Function works in windows but doesn't in linux

Tags: c, null, user-input, c-strings

I've been learning C for like 5 days, and so I tried doing some little projects.
I created a very simple library that automates getting a string from the user,then implemented it in a program which just outputs the string's value.

It runs perfectly on Windows (Compiled through MSVC: **'cl .\main.c /link .\get_string\m_string.obj'**) but it doesn't in Linux (Compiled with gcc using : **'gcc -o test main.c m_string.o'**)

*I know that MAX being 1024 makes absolutely no sense, it's just a test value.*

```
//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "get_string/m_string.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *inputf = get_string("Something: ");
  printf("%s", inputf);
  return 0;
}
```

```
// m_string.h
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1024
char *get_string(char *prompt);
```

```
//m_string.c
#include "m_string.h"
char *get_string(char *prompt)
{
  char *s[MAX]; 
  printf("%s", prompt);
  fgets(s, MAX, stdin);
  return s;
}
```

Running main.c on Windows works as expected:

```
Something: something
something
```

Running main.c on Linux:

```
Something: something
(null)$
```

Since I am using a very big value for the maximum memory used in **fgets()**, I don't think that a buffer overflow is the cause (Would have probably gotten **Segmentation Fault** otherwise).

Thank you for reading and I hope someone can shed some light on the matter for an absolute beginer like me.

Comment: `char *s[MAX];` needs to be `char s[MAX];`. Equally  important, `s` is a local variable with lifetime only within the function. Using a reference to it outside the function is Undefined Behaviour. UB means it can crash, produce wrong results and even appear to "work" at times - but can break with any unrelated changes to code or the environment.

Comment: Please don't tag C++ if you are writing and asking about C.

Comment: @kaylum there's a lot more undefined behavior going on here because of that little typo.

Comment: How did this ever compile without errors?

Comment: @kaylum Thank you for your answer, very informative as well, since I'm very new to C didn't know much about UB.

Comment: @MarkRansom well, i wish i knew.

Comment: The compiler should have definitely thrown warnings, even without special flags. But basically you should never compile without `-Werror`, and it is generally recommended to also warn for lots of basic mistakes using `-Wall`. So try `gcc -Wall -Werror -o test main.c m_string.o`

Comment: [Answer](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/a5fdc62c8f79de05cfaee8b1e5332d62) I was writing to your deleted question

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the effort! I realized my code was trash, so I tried not to bother people to help me with my sphagetti code. Thanks a lot though brother!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `char *s[MAX];` creates an array of `MAX` pointers, not `char` values.

   ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. It would have found this. With gcc, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.
2. `get_string` returns a pointer to a variable that no longer exists once `get_string` returns.

   One way to solve this is to allocate a buffer using `malloc`, and `free` that buffer in the caller.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 1024

char *get_string( const char *prompt ) {
   char *s = malloc( MAX );
   if ( !s )
      return NULL;

   printf( "%s", prompt );

   if ( !fgets( s, MAX, stdin ) ) {
      free( s );
      return NULL;
   }

   return s;
}

int main( void ) {
  char *inputf = get_string( "Something: " );
  if ( !inputf ) {
     perror( NULL );
     exit( 1 );
  }

  printf( "%s", inputf );

  free( inputf );

  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WcPbd5Wxv) on Compiler Explorer

Answer (score 2):

It really does *not* run "correctly", because this is undefined behavior. You may not access temporary storage outside of the scope in which it was defined.

In addition to this, you also have a type error: `char *s[MAX];` defines an array of `MAX` char *pointers*. Using this as a string buffer should not have been allowed past the compiler.

If you do not want to allocate memory dynamically for this, then make the string buffer static. You can even make it thread-local (since C11) if for some reason you plan to use this function in concurrent environments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1024

char *get_string(const char *prompt)
{
  static _Thread_local char s[MAX];
  printf("%s", prompt);

  if (!fgets(s, MAX, stdin)) {
      s[0] = '\0';
  }

  return s;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *inputf = get_string("Something: ");
  printf("%s", inputf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm still trying to understand pointers fully.